# saving n factor means in same data frame in r

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I'm looking for a better option saving a group mean directly in the same data frame in a new column. I usually solve this problem in the following steps shown below. Is there a possibility of saving the means without merging them explicitly but doing i right away maybe with dplyr?

```
data <- data.frame(group  = rep(c("low","high"),2),
                   values = runif(n = 4, min = 0, max = 2))

data_mean <- data %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise (mean(values))

merge(data_mean, data)

  group mean(values)     values
1  high    0.2889459 0.07079697
2  high    0.2889459 0.50709475
3   low    0.7767188 0.93176182
4   low    0.7767188 0.62167588
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `mutate` instead of `summarise` should do what you want:

```
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(values))

#Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
#Groups: group
#
#  group    values      mean
#1   low 1.4017168 0.7478336
#2  high 0.8074821 1.1018971
#3   low 0.0939505 0.7478336
#4  high 1.3963122 1.1018971
```

Note: my values are different from yours because you didn't use `set.seed` for reproducibility of random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `tapply` in base R

```
within(data, means <- tapply(values, group, mean, na.rm=TRUE))
#   group    values    means
# 1   low 1.1069518 1.515846
# 2  high 1.6729194 1.001568
# 3   low 0.8961838 1.515846
# 4  high 1.3587732 1.001568
```